# Select 2nd Element of a Table using Xpath

Tags: xpath, selection

How can I select the text field (which is in 2nd column of the table)On binance Top Gainers page

when I search using this query, it will select the first row

`(//*[contains(@data-type, 'table-td')])[1]`

and same for 2nd row
`(//*[contains(@data-type, 'table-td')])[2]`

I need to select the 2nd element of this table using xpath (only the text field) (RIF and STX) in this case.

Top Gainers Table on Binance

[image: 1]

Or is there a way to get only the text for first and 2nd row

It gave me only the table row.. I need to select the 2nd element of the table.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be :

```
//div[text()="Top Gainers"]/ancestor::div[2]//div[@class][./img]/div[@title]/@title
```

or

```
//div[text()="Top Gainers"]/ancestor::div[2]//div[@class][./img]/div[@title]/text()
```

Output : 10 items

URL used : https://www.binance.com/en/markets/overview/topmovers